# Getting two sender values instead of one for particular case?

Tags: ios, uibutton, ibaction, sender

I am having a IBAction for 4 buttons which represent 4 available answers and each time I press a button I read the sender ID, then it figures out if answer is correct and so on.

Now I have a special case, when another button (nothing in common with those 4 buttons) is pressed, it waits for two of these answers, checks if one of them is correct( i know how to do that) and then the program continues running.

So for now, I have :

```
- (IBAction)answerButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString* answer= [[sender titleLabel] text];

   //checks if answer key is equal to a1 ( which is always the correct answer )
    if([[currentQuestionUsefulVariable valueForKey:@"a1"] isEqualToString:answer] ){

        correctQuestionsCount1 ++;
    }
    //answer is wrong
    else{
        wrongQuestionsCount1 ++;
    }
}
```

*As you see I store the answer string in a variable called answer*

And again - All I need is to store two answers and check the two of them when this special button is pressed. I will of course put a boolean variable to indicate when it is pressed and it will do the work.

EDIT: 
The two answer thing is when I press a specific joker button and it gives the advantage to the user to chose two of four available answers. This is why I need to do that. For any other cases I need only one answer at a time.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're going to need an instance variable, the value of which persists throughout the lifetime of the object, and perhaps using a mutable array of the answers is the way forward:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *_correctAnswers;
}
```

It must be initialised in `viewDidLoad` (other options are available):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _correctAnswers = [NSMutableArray new];
}
```

and then start collecting correct answers into this array:

```
- (IBAction)answerButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSString* answer= [[sender titleLabel] text];

   //checks if answer key is equal to a1 ( which is always the correct answer )
    if([[currentQuestionUsefulVariable valueForKey:@"a1"] isEqualToString:answer] ){
        [_correctAnswers addObject:answer];
    }
    //answer is wrong
    else{
        wrongQuestionsCount1 ++;
    }

    if ([_correctAnswers count] == 2) {
        // Do something?  It's not exactly clear what you want to do
        // when 2 correct answers have been given.
    }
}
```

Note: you can dump `correctQuestionsCount1` as that will be `[_correctAnswers count]` now.  Also you will need to reset the array at some point.

Note 2: You could also start collecting incorrect answers as well, for some analysis or perhaps to disable that button so the user cannot repeatedly answer the question wrong.

Comment: I am trying it right now and I will update it in few minutes.
To make things clear - I have a running program that gets one answer at a time and everything's good. The two answer thing is when I press a specific joker button and it gives the advantage to the user to chose two of four available answers. This is why I need to do that. For any other cases I need only one answer at a time.  
As I see , you add the answer to the array, after the ( if answer is correct check is done) . I need to fill the array with two answers, THEN -> check if one of these two is okay.
Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: Hmm, I think I've got it wrong in my answer then.  Sounds to me like all you want to do is enable/disable certain buttons to make the answer easier to guess?

Comment: I updated my comment above. 
The only thing left is to

first :  (if joker button pressed) -> fill the array with two answers, THEN -> check if one of these two is okay. That's simply everything i need. But I need the program to freeze while two answer button are being pressed. I don't want to jump to another question when only one is pressed. That's the catch.

Comment: But if you have a UI with 4 buttons containing different answers and the user presses the "easy mode" button, then isn't it enough to disable two of the wrong answer buttons so the user can ignore them (and cannot even select them)?  It doesn't sound like you need to make any changes anywhere else?

Comment: You just got in the "50/50" joker case, which is already done. And yes, i just remove two wrong answers.
In my case you can mark two wrong answers and still don't get a point for a correct question. That's the game :)
The case i am working now is called Double Dip. 
You press the joker , and now you can mark two answers and see if you get one of them correct.

Comment: Ah OK.  My answer goes some way towards that then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64880/discussion-between-xdevx-and-trojanfoe).